# Squaring values in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have been asked to create a function that calls a function `void square(vector<int> &v)` that squares each integer in the vector `v`. Here is what I have, but I keep getting a compiler error.
Any help given would be greatly appreciated

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void square(vector<int> &v)
{
  for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++){
    v = v[i]*v[i];
  }
}
```

here is my comp error:

```
'void square(std::vector<int>&)':
editor.cpp:11:13: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'v = ((& v)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<int, std::allocator<int> >(((std::vector<int>::size_type)i)) * (& v)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<int, std::allocator<int> >(((std::vector<int>::size_type)i)))'
editor.cpp:11:13: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/vector:70:0,
                 from editor.cpp:3:
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/vector.tcc:161:5: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/vector.tcc:161:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'const std::vector<int>&'
```

Comment: *What* compiler error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are trying to assign integer to a vector.
2. `size` is a class method and should called as `v.size()`

Here is a valid code:

```
void square(vector<int> &v)
{
  for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++){
    v[i] = v[i]*v[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:

```
i<v.size
```

`size` is a member function in `std::vector`, not a field.  Try changing the expression to read

```
i < v.size()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to correct both problems:

v.size

should be

v.size()

and the re-assignment should be

v[i] = v[i]*v[i];